# Riemann integration on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

see the attached problem below

[image]

My thoughts on (6) are as follows, if we can show that $h$ is continuous on the interval $[0,1]$ then $h$ must be integrable on $[0,1]$ also? my problem is how do i show that a function like this is continuous as it is piecewise?

Problem (7) will just be using the definition of being differentiable i assume?
and for problem(8) we will be able to apply the same method as that of in  6 to the derivative of h?

can anyone let me know if i'm along the right lines with my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\cos(1/x^2)&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

For $x\ne 0$, $f(x)$ is the composition of continuous functions and is, therefore, a continuous function.

We also have $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0=f(0)$ and so, $f(x)$ is everywhere continuous and hence Riemann integrable on every closed interval.

---

To show that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere, we first note that $f(x)$ is differentiable for $x\ne0$ since it is composed of differentiable functions.  For $x=0$ we find that

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\cos(1/h^2)-0}{h}=0$$

So, $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ and can be written

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x\cos(1/x^2)+\frac{2\sin(1/x^2)}{x}&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases} \tag 2$$

---

However, since $f'(x)$ as given in $(2)$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $x=0$, then it cannot be Riemann integrable there.

Comment: Brilliant, do you think that i would need to go back to the definition of continuity to show that $\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$ is continuous

Comment: Thank you.  Much appreciated.  To show $\cos(1/x^2)$ is continuous for $x\ne0$, note that $1/x^2$ and $\cos(x)$ are continuous for $x\ne 0$.  Therefore the composition is continuous too.

Comment: ahh great, could explain the reasoning for the last part, how is it unbounded?

Comment: Sure.  Note that $\left|\frac{\sin(1/x^2)}{x}\right|$ can be made arbitrarily  large near $x=0$.  Take $x^2=\frac{1}{\pi/2 +n\pi}$, $n\ge 0$.  Then, $|\sin(1/x^2)|=1$ and $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|=\sqrt{\pi/2+n\pi}\to \infty$  as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: also could you show me using the definition how you found $f'(x)$ for when $x$ doesnt equal 0, also how can you simplify the fraction for $f'(0)$  because if we was to take the limit of that we would have a division by 0 inside the cosine term? do i need to use the sandwich theorem for derivatives ?

Comment: To obtain $f'$ for $x\ne0$, we use the chain rule and the product rule.  For the limit used to compute $f'(0)$, note that $h^2/h=h$ for $h\ne0$ and the cosine function is bounded in absolute value by $1$.

Comment: ah okay, but when using the chain rule and product rule do we need to use the standard definition or can we just differentiate it normal like that of a course in calculus or differential equations

Comment: We can use those things we've already proven.  So, for example, $\frac{d\cos(x)}{dx}=-\sin(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(1/x^2)=-2/x^3$.

Comment: is it possible to differentiate f(x) using just the standard definition?

Comment: If you mean that the standard definition is the limit of the difference quotient, then yes, it is possible, but quites unnecessary and likely very "messy."